# How to use STL max from include <algorithm> for user defined data type

Tags: c++, stl

I have a simple class

```
class sample
{
    int i;

    public:
    sample(int i): i(i){}

};

int main()
{  
    cout << max (12, 26) << endl; // working fine
    sample s1(10), s2(20);
    cout << max (s1, s2);  // lots of compilation errors
    return 0; 
}
```

i want max (s1, s2) should return max of max (s1, s2). I know i am missing some thing, but not able to picturise the things.

Any help will be appreciated.

Devesh

Comment: try reading the errors, they tell you exactly what is missing.

Comment: unnecessary downvotes

Comment: @AliAlamiri: Read the downvote mouseover text again

Comment: @PlasmaHH The question IS clear and useful. I've actually learnt something new because of this question. The question meets every SO criteria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options: First, implement an `operator<`, for example,

```
bool operator<(const sample& lhs, const sample& rhs)
{
  return lhs.i < rhs.i;
}
```

Note that in this particular case, `i` is `private`, so the operator above would have to be declared a `friend` of `sample`. Alternatively, you can use a member<sup>1</sup>:

```
class sample
{
  // as before ...

  bool operator<(const sample& rhs) const { return i < rhs.i; }
};
```

Second, use the overload that takes a binary comparison functor, so you can say

```
std::max(s1, s2, comp);
```

where `comp` can be something like

```
bool comp(const sample& lhs, const sample& rhs)
{
  return lhs.i < rhs.i; // or other logic
}
```

<sup>1 A non-member is preferred because it has perfect symmetry between LHS and RHS. This is not the case when using a member. This can be an issue when using implicit converting constructors</sup>

Comment: Another option would be to implement a specialization of `std::max`, right?

Comment: @MagnusHoff I guess that would be allowed. However, I prefer the two options above: either determine max according to the less-than operator, or be explicit about the comparison you use. Specializing `std::max` could hide the comparison logic or make it inconsistent with an existing `operator<`.

Comment: Can you use a lambda instead of passing a function?

Comment: isnt it better to just define max, not specialize std::max, and let ADL have its 5 minutes of glory

Comment: I am trying to use the first way that you have suggested. But it is giving the same compilation error.

error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << std::max [with _Tp = sample](((const sample&)((const sample*)(& s1))), ((const sample&)((const sample*)(& s2))))’

Comment: Note that in the OPs code `i` is private, so both these versions wouldn't compile. They'd have to be declared as friends or use an indirection via a member function.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal it is probably because `sample::i` is private. You would have to make the operator a `friend`.

Comment: Yes i is private. This is the declaration i have added in class definition.

friend bool operator< (const sample& lhs, const sample& rhs);

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal that error is because you are trying to pass a `sample` to `std::cout`. You need to overload yet another operator for that. But that is a different question, and there are plenty of duplicates of it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
class sample
{

    public:
    int i;
    sample(int i): i(i){}
    bool operator< (const sample& other) const
    {
        return i < other.i;
    }

};

int main()
{  
    sample s1(10), s2(20);
    max (s1, s2); 
    return 0; 
}
```

note `const` after `operator <` , it is important. :)